# Google App Engine dev_appserver throws error 'python2: command not found' after upgrade to Python 3

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sdk, google-cloud-sdk

Until yesterday I was successfully using the `dev_appserver.py app.yaml --enable_console` for my development.
Yesterday I attempted to upgrade to python 3.7 for my development.
The upgrade seemed to be Ok, but now I get the following error message.

```
server:bones brian$ dev_appserver.py app.yaml --enable_console
ERROR: (dev_appserver) python2: command not found
```

app.yaml:

```
application: bones 
version: 1
runtime: python37
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

I am using Mac OS X 10.11.6.

Why is dev_appserver even looking for python2?
And how can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesnt look like you can fix that:

> Running dev_appserver requires the presence of Python 2.7.12+ on your local machine.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/testing-and-deploying-your-app#local-dev-server

Comment: Your answer worked and I greatly appreciate your answer. But I am really confused now about going onward. I depend on the following imports and I don't see any easy way to get them in this 3.7 environment: ndb, jinja2, webapp2, json. Can I return to the previous version of dev_appserver, and if not, what can I read to learn how to minimally alter my code to move onward? Btw, is jinja2 (and any others in my list) now embedded or do I need to import django (and similarly for the other)? Is datastore very like ndb? I really want to continue with appengine, but the hurdles mount.

Comment: datastore is not like `ndb`, there is a new `ndb` lib called `google-cloud-ndb` you should look at. as for the others cant you just put them in your requirements.txt? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/specifying-dependencies
And why do you need to return to a previous version of `dev_appserver`?

Comment: @zerowords the newer Python 3 environment for AppEngine uses Flask, which includes jinja2 (you don't need to specify jinja2 in requirements.txt), and removes the dependencies on  webapp2 (you'll use Flask's request handlers). As mentioned in the comment above, google-cloud-ndb will replace the bare ndb library that you were using in python27. The json library should still be available. Sorry that this doesn't help with the question, but hopefully it helps with migration to the Python 3 environment.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in other answers, dev_appserver requires Python 2.7.12+

**OSX users will need to run:**

```
brew install pr0d1r2/python2/python@2.7.17 --build-from-source
```

I would have added this as a comment to previous answers but I don't have enough stackoverflow creds

Comment: In case, above method doesn't work, install python2 on OSX by following instructions here: https://blog.tericcabrel.com/install-python2-on-macos/

Answer (score 2):

**(Aug 2021)**

**TL;DR:**
Regardless of whether your app is Python 2 or 3, running the `dev_appserver` using Python 2 or 3 *requires* a Python 2 interpreter.

**LONG:** The wording was recently changed to, "Running `dev_appserver` requires Python 2.7.12 or newer on your local machine." That is still unclear, so I filed a bug to make it more explicit. Once it gets approved, the text will say something to the effect of: "**Note:** Running `dev_appserver.py` requires that you have a Python 2 interpreter with a version of 2.7.12 or newer installed on your local machine. This is true for all runtimes in the App Engine standard environment."

The bottom-line is that while you can run `dev_appserver.py` with either Python 2 or 3, the underlying processing it does still requires a Python 2 interpreter to be present. There's a bug filed against the tool to convert it completely to Python 3 however, but there's no ETA on when that's coming.

Comment: "python 2 or newer" means python 3 should be fine too, right?  EXCEPT IT ISN'T (and I think this is what you are trying to convey). I was able to get it working by using "pyenv" app (install through homebrew) then installing this version: `pyenv install 2.7.18`, then setting that version in the file: `~/.pyenv/version`

Comment: Glad you got it working. "Python 2.7.12 or newer" means 2.7.13, 14., one so on. IOW (in other words), a "newer" version of Python 2.7. I also added some clarification to my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a Python 3.7 Google App Engine project and am unable to execute the `dev_appserver.py` command for the same reason (`python2: command not found`). For various reasons, it isn't feasible to downgrade to Python 2.7.

I don't think [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61506922/5628028) here (that `dev_appserver.py` is only meant to work with Python 2.7) is accurate; the GAE documentation for Python 3.7 in fact [lists](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/tools/local-devserver-command) `dev_appserver.py` as an option for local development. This seems more like a `gcloud` bug.

(Note: I know this would be better as a comment on the previous answer, but because I'm a new-ish SO user, I don't yet have permission to post comments)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am really frustrated with python 3.7 because of all the mess with different pip versions and different virtual environments (and so on) needed for GAE. I cannot seem to get beyond all the errors my actions throw. I have retired to python 2.7 almost completely. I would love to read about how to maintain both 3.7 and 2.7 on my Mac. It appears my PATH is so confused it cannot cope now, so that is where I especially need help.

Comment: @jtotoole Coming to this late. Yes, dev_appserver is an option for local development for Python3 but it still requires python2.7 to work (to invoke it). Google themselves recommend YOU DO NOT use dev_appserver to run python3 env. They say ```We recommend that you use standard Python tools, such as virtualenv to create isolated environments and pytest to run unit tests and integration tests, rather than depending on dev_appserver``` So, the accepted answer is correct and it is not a gcloud bug.

Answer (score 1):

Just need python2 installed on the computer (even if your application is in python3).

So, the solution is just :

```
sudo apt-get install python2 python2-dev
```