# Unable to Debug Dev Appserver using pycharm, but able to run fine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pycharm, dev-appserver

Attempting to run a python 2.7 app engine app locally using PyCharm (which uses dev_appserver) my machine is python 3.7 but I have a python 2.7 virtual env setup as the project interpreter, which works fine when running the project.

However when attempting to debug the same run config (which runs fine) I am getting the following error

`ERROR: (dev_appserver) python2: command not found`

I can run the `python2` command in my terminal both inside and outside the virtual environment so I am not sure what is wrong here.

I am currently running Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS if that helps.

Comment: I think your pycharm configuration is not picking up you virtual environment configuration and hence producing this message which is already addressed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61503849/google-dev-appserver-throws-error-python2-command-not-found-after-upgrade-to

Comment: @AntonioRamirez So this would seem a PyCharm Bug? The Debugger is not using the configured interpreter and instead reverting to the system interpreter?

Comment: I have the same issue, and discovered that the server will run if "Attach to subprocess automatically while debugging" is deselected, however this means no breakpoints, so is pretty useless. Still - this may trigger a thought process for anyone reading ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue on mac catalina with Pycharm 2020.1.2.
I was able to start the debugger by using a "Python configuration", rather than a "App Engine Server" configuration. Steps below:

1. Click "Edit Configurations", and add a new "Python Configuration"
2. In the Script Path, enter the full path to dev_appserver.py
3. In Parameters, enter '--max_module_instances="default:1" .' (according to https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server#debugging_with_pdb)
4. In Working Directory, enter the path to your project

This isn't perfect, but at least you can run the debugger within pycharm.

I look forward to a better answer some day that works with the "App Engine Server" configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after starting new AppEngine projects on python 3. Initially, I thought the problem was with a new version of Google Cloud SDK. I spent a lot of time linking/unlinking python versions and playing around the environment variables.
But eventually, update of PyCharm to 2021.1.2 fixed the issue.